# Behaviour of XCTest unclear failing on assertTrue

Tags: xcode, xctest

The XCTest suite of xCode seems buggy, am i missing something or why does the following test fail some times when switching values between true and false sometimes the test continues to fail with a true value hardcoded!

```
-(void) testDescDefaultEmpty{
    XCTAssertTrue(true, @"The description was incorrect");

}
```

It seems it doesnt clear out the old tests on running new ones..

Comment: And sometimes it just skipps all the tests of a class!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the assert to this:

```
XCTAssertTrue(YES, @"The description was incorrect");
```